# IntelliJ Java code style for texts block alignment

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm looking for the option, or a plugin, that fix this issue on IntelliJ :

When doing multi-line block text, I would like to keep the beginning of the line aligned.
Doing auto-reformatting (Ctrl-Alt-L) mis-align the lines :

[image: mis aligned block text]

I would like it to stay like this :

[image: aligned]

I found some option in code-style settings, but nothing that fixed this, even the well named "Align when multiline" in Texts block section. Or I don't know how to make text block !

Comment: afaik, Continuation Indent feature does not help for this. I'd add `//@formatter:off` above sql statement literal and add `//@formatter:on` below the end of the sql statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the `Align when multiline` option under `Binary expressions` you're looking for

Comment: Was just about to add this as an answer myself. This does indeed work.

Comment: Oh yes ! I can ctrl-alt-L all my document and don't mind about this :D You made my day